# Java8 - item of array exists in an other array

Tags: java-8

Is there a simple way of check, if an item of array1 exists in array2?

```
List<String> array1 = new ArrayList<>();
array1.add("Hello");
array1.add("Test");

List<String> array2 = new ArrayList<>();
array2.add("Test");
array2.add("Item");
```

So, "Test" is in array1 and array2, therefore the answer should be true.
Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: Yes. By writing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use simple functional style:

```
List<String> result = array1.stream()
    .filter(array2::contains)
    .collect(Collectors.roList());
```

Answer (score 2):

`Collections.disjoint(collection1, collection2)` returns `true` if `collection1` and `collection2` have no elements in common.

So in your case, `boolean haveElementsInCommon = !Collections.disjoint(array1, array2)` would do the job, at least, as I understand the question.

Please check [`Collections.disjoint()` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint-java.util.Collection-java.util.Collection-) for details.